# Combobox c# bloquear seleccion

Tags: c#, combobox

Bien mi pregunta en cuestión es: 
- Tengo varias Windows Form para hacerlo más visual y tal, cuando tu vas a donde está la tabla y seleccionas el valor que quieras en el combobox si luego vuelves hacia atrás y luego retomas donde lo dejaste el valor seleccionado se elimina, hay alguna manera de dejarlo fijo lo que selecciones en el combobox mientras esté abierta la app?

Muchas gracias y perdón si no me explico muy bien...

Comment: Agrega el codigo y clases que estas trabajando.

Comment: De momento no tengo nada, voy probando sobre la marcha ya que estoy aprendiendo, simplemente esto: comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("OK");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("NOT OK"); 
La cuestión es que cuando cambio de form, el valor que había seleccionado desaparece y quiero que se mantenga.
Gracias

Comment: podes guardarlo en una clase static

Comment: Agregar el codigo que hiciste y explica el flujo entre las clases para entender el problema

Answer (score 0):

no soy experto pero lo único que se me ocurre es guardar una variable string con el valor y después igualas el texto del combo box al valor de la variable string.

```
string sel = combo_box.Text;
// Haces lo que necesites.
combo_box.Text = sel;
```

Comment: No es ese el problema que tiene

Comment: Pues entonces no entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: Cuando parece que cierra el formulario y vuelve al mismo abriendolo de nuevo, vuelve a instanciar, le falta colocar el codigo de lo que hace. Para terminar de entender el problema.

Comment: Si al cerrar el formulario, cierras la aplicación, no hay otra solución más que guardarlo en un archivo y entiendo que eso sería algo extraño. Y si por el contrario simplemente vuelves al formulario anterior, se puede hacer como he dicho pero guardando la variable en el formulario padre y pasandolo como parámetro o algo así. Pero como dices, si hubiese aportado el código sería más sencillo ponerme en situación :)